# What is a solid approach to change passwords in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

My script is supposed work like that:

- Insert the Old password and
- then the New Passsword.

The old password is working and checked but when i insert the new password the code no work... without errors, nothing...

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$user_p = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    header("Location: live.php");      
    die("Redirecting to live.php"); 
} 

if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    $currentPassword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['currentPassword']);
    $newPassword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['newPassword']); 
    $oldpass = IrBuscarPassword($_SESSION['user']['username']);
    $saltcode = IrBuscarSalt($_SESSION['user']['username']);

    $formEncriptedPass = hash('sha256', $currentPassword . $saltcode); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $formEncriptedPass = hash('sha256', $formEncriptedPass . $saltcode); 
        } 

    $changepass = False;

    if($oldpass != $formEncriptedPass)
    {   
        echo "Password NO-OK.";
        //die();
    }
    else
    {

        if($newPassword == '')
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] = " The field E-mail is empty.</span></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            if($newPassword == '' || !isset($newPassword))
            {
                $changepass = False;

            } 
            else
            {

                $changepass = True;
                atualizarMail($newPassword, $_SESSION['user']['username']);
            }
        }

    }


    if(!isset($currentPassword) || ($currentPassword == ''))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = " The Password field is empty.</span></div>";
    }

    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['currentPassword'] . $saltcode); 


    if($changepass == False)
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "<br/>New Password.</span></div>";
    }


    if($_POST['newPassword'] != $_SESSION['user']['username']) 
    { 


        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                password = :newPassword 
        "; 


        $query_params = array( 
            ':newPassword' => $_POST['newPassword'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 

            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

    }

    if(!empty($_POST['newPassword'])) 
    { 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['newPassword'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $password = null; 
        $salt = null; 
    } 
        if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
        {
            echo $_SESSION['error']; 

            $_SESSION['error'] = null;
        }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user']['password'] = $_POST['newPassword']; 
        $_SESSION['success'] = " The password has been successfully changed..</span></div>";

        header("Location: password.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to logout.php"); 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `insert new password` where? I don't see any insert query here.

Comment: There is no `INSERT` statement in your code at all...

Comment: Yes is there but in Function, not there...

" -----> atualizarMail <---     ($newPassword, $_SESSION['user']['username']);"

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems and is difficult to read/understand. Some examples:

- You check for the same things again and again `if($newPassword == '')`
- You do different things in one function `atualizarMail()`
- Your hash function is unsafe and not future proof. It is implemented in at least 3 places. Storing the salt could be done much easier.
- Passwords should not be sanitized, only validated (no `preg_replace()`)
- The line `if($_POST['newPassword'] != $_SESSION['user']['username'])` doesn't make much sense.
- There are too many levels of `if` statements, combined with using states `$changepass` (hard to read, easy to do a mistake)
- The query `SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE password = :newPassword` will hopefully never fetch any data, because only the hash is stored in the database.

I hope i could point out, why i recommend to start from scratch, after reading a good tutorial. Maybe i can give you some ideas to start width:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

The second function password_verify() can be used for login as well as to check if the old password matches.

Another tip, validate all input at the start of your script and redirect immediately if there are any problems. After doing validation, do not check again for invalid input, just use it.